# Toda a vez que clico para ir em outra pagina, pede o login novamente (LARAVEL 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel, session, auth

Boa tarde pessoal

Toda vez que vou para outra página minha aplicação pede para refazer o login

Segue route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Auth::routes();

Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('/create', 'CreateController@create')->name('create');
    Route::get('/query', 'CreateController@query')->name('query');
    Route::get('/detalhes', ['as'=>'detalhes', 'uses'=> 'CreateController@detalhes']);
    Route::get('/tarefas', ['as'=>'tarefas', 'uses'=> 'CreateController@tarefas']);
    Route::post('/store', ['as'=>'store', 'uses'=> 'CreateController@store']);
    Route::post('/delete', ['as' => 'delete' , 'uses' => 'CreateController@delete']);
    Route::post('/alterar', ['as' => 'alterar' , 'uses' => 'CreateController@alterar']);
    Route::post('/update', ['as' => 'update' , 'uses' => 'CreateController@update']);

});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Controller home:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * CreateController a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Não sei especificamente aonde é o problema ainda, se precisar de mais informações encaminho

Comment: Você está usando o middleware auth em todas as rotas, esse middleware faz com que todas as rotas sejam acessíveis somente com usuário logado.

Comment: Então, é esse o intuito, que o acesso seja fornecido somente para usuários logados, o ponto é que, se eu estou na pagina HOME e clico para ir na pagina CREATE ele me redireciona para a pagina de LOGIN, porém, eu já estava logado.

Comment: Usa isso no seu controller: echo '<pre>'; print_r( auth()->user() ); die;
Se retornar algo é pq o usuário está realmente logado, se não vc vai ter que debugar o método de login para ver pq ele não está persistindo a sessão do usuário.

Comment: @KayoBruno Amigo já consegui resolver o problema, era uma coisa bem básica,em uma das minhas views estava passando em um href={{ Auth::Logout() }}, e toda a vez que recarregava a pagina esse método era chamado, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda :)